# uninitialized move in std::vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory, memory-management, stl

I use visual studio 2010 and its stl implementation is from [dinkumware](http://www.dinkumware.com)

I noticed that when internal buffer of vector grows, there is a _Uninitialized_move is called. which is much like std::uninitialized_copy.

1. for scalar type, it eventually forwards call to memmove
2. for non-scalar type, it will call copy constructor of contained type.

I know that for non-scalar type, bit-wise coping isn't safe, but I am get confused in this case, because the old objects will be destroyed very soon. it looks like that bit-wise coping for all types is safe, and hence we only need free raw buffer after _Uninitialized_move. this will save lots of copy constructor and destructor for non-trivial objects.

so, is it safe to just move contents for non-scalar type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're completely sure that objects you move don't have pointers to each other (subobjects of those included) - then just moving contents is okay. However you can't know that unless you know how the type is designed inside. One exception is that if the type is not larger than a pointer (`sizeof(Type) <= sizeof( void* )`), then it is very unlikely to have pointers to objects in the same container, so usually it can be just moved.

Comment: @Chang: There might be weird issues with treating scalars with `memmove()`, but they are rather unlikely.

Answer (score 4):

In C++11, there are many traits to know whether it is safe to perform bit operations or not.

In your case, I think you should use [`std::is_trivially_move_constructible<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_constructible). Those traits are implemented using compiler intrinsics (non-portable, that's why it's in the Standard Library), but they are themselves portable.

Therefore, the code should be akin to:

```
template <typename T>
void move_to(T* storage, T* begin, T* end) {
  if (std::is_trivially_move_constructible<T>::value) {
    memmove(storage, begin, (end - begin) * sizeof(T));
  } else {
    for (; begin != end; ++begin, ++storage) {
      new (storage) T(std::move(*begin));
    }
  }
}
```

And the compiler will optimize the `if` at compilation time depending on whether the type is trivially move constructible or not and only leave the interesting branch.

Comment: Thanks for let me know "is_trivially_move_constructible"

Answer (score 1):

No. If they have pointers to each other then simple bit-wise move will invalidate those.

Comment: If they have pointers to each other, then copy construction followed by destroying the source will also produce dead pointers. If they have pointers into themselves, then copy construction is OK but bitwise copy isn't.

Comment: I had a feeling something was off with what I posted (after I posted). I would assume copy constructor in such cases would have to be more intelligent and copy data from those pointers (or hidden to disallow such behaviour). But much simpler explanation are pointers-to-self as you said.